# Wordpress - backend AJAX call returning 0

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have create a backend plugin for my website and I would like it to work with AJAX. But all I am getting from the AJAX response is readyState: 4 and responseText: 0.

**script.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            action: 'my_action', 
            param: 'st1' 
        },
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        success : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

**members_loop.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_ajax_action_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_ajax_action_function');

function my_ajax_action_function(){
    $reponse = array();

    if(!empty($_POST['param'])){
         $response['response'] = "I've get the param a its value is ".$_POST['param'].' and the plugin url is '.plugins_url();
    } else {
         $response['response'] = "You didn't send the param";
    }

    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo json_encode($response);

    wp_die();
}
```

I am using three files inside my plugin to do this, I have my plugin.php file where I declare my plugin and enqueue my script.js file. Then I have a templates file with two folders inside it one being members_loop.php and the other index.php (The "homepage" for the plugin). Then I have an assets file with my script.js file. Not sure if this information is needed but I don't think my ajax call is wrong so I'm wondering what is going wrong.

**Issue Update**

I just cut and paste the my_ajax_my_action funciton and the actions to the plugin.php file where I declare the plugin and now it works. So how do I get it to work in an external file? do I have to require the members_loop.php file inside the plugin.php file?

Comment: Can you try and remove the `wp_die()`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Just tried it and got the same result

Comment: @Reece are you try to `require_once` your "members_loop.php" file inside "plugin.php"?

Comment: @Rimarx I believe thats what I need to do, I have tried it but I can't get the syntax correct for require_once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file path is "/wp-content/plugins/your_plugin/members_loop.php", so inside file "plugin.php" add `require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'members_loop.php';` or `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/members_loop.php';`

Comment: Still getting an error Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/plugin/members_loop.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/plugin/plugin.php on line 70

Comment: @Reece write your path to the file "members_loop.php"